# I downloaded Live Speech to Text by Watson and I got this problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, websphere, ibm-cloud

I have downloaded Live Speech to Text with Watson Speech to Text and Python from :
https://github.com/nicknochnack/RealTimeSpeechToText

I put the apikey and the region in RealTimeSpeechToText-main\watson-streaming-stt\speech.cfg"

I don't know why this problem appears :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Ahmad Sadek\Desktop\RealTimeSpeechToText-main\watson-streaming-stt\transcribe.py", line 222, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\Ahmad Sadek\Desktop\RealTimeSpeechToText-main\watson-streaming-stt\transcribe.py", line 197, in main
    userpass = ":".join(get_auth())
  File "c:\Users\Ahmad Sadek\Desktop\RealTimeSpeechToText-main\watson-streaming-stt\transcribe.py", line 180, in get_auth
    apikey = config.get('auth', 'apikey')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser.py", line 782, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\configparser.py", line 1153, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'auth'
```

You have downloaded :
pyaudio
websocket-client

I am using Python 3.10.2 win 11 pro

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error:

```
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'auth'
```

The configuration file is missing an `auth` section.

Looking at the sample.

```
[auth]
apikey = <YOUR API KEY>
# Modify region based on where you provisioned your stt instance 
region = <YOUR REGION>
```

My guess is that you have deleted / edited the line `[auth]`

Comment: didn't work. same problem

Comment: Please add a redacted version of the configuration file that you are using to your question. My hunch is that that is the source of the error.